# Automating Nested If Statements and Incrementing Counter--Javascript

Tags: javascript

Anyone know how I code automate this dynamically for the .length of data.all? I am trying to make it so if consecutive avgs (starting from the first avg) are not equal to null, increment fun. Here is the code

```
var fun = 0;
if(data.all[0].avg != null){
    fun++;
    if(data.all[1].avg != null){
        fun++;
        if(data.all[2].avg != null){
            fun++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want [recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010451/automating-nested-if-statements-and-incrementing-counter-javascript#comment50047795_31010451).

Comment: @ssube Maybe. I am trying to make it so if consecutive avgs (starting from the first avg) are not equal to null, increment fun.

Comment: You seem to be looking for **loops**!

Answer (score 1):

```
var fun = 0;
data.all.some(function (el) {
    if (el.avg) {
        fun++;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: You're going right but missing to check for not null.

Comment: @Nina thanks for the reply but I need it so if consecutive avgs, starting from the first avg, are not equal to null then increment fun. Not just if it is not equal to fun.

Comment: @ Bhojendra Nepal  isn't if(el.avg) checking for nulls?

Comment: @KennyUSC, now it should work. maybe you can supply some data for testing? what do you mean with `null`? the check does include check for null.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work! Thanks everyone for the feedback!

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.all.length; i++){
    if (data.all[i].avg == null) break;
        fun++;
}
```